# Youtube-dl --playlist-reverse and --playlist-start not working together

Tags: youtube-dl

I've written a script for Youtube-dl which scans the number of files in a folder then starts downloading from a playlist from that number so that it only downloads new songs from that playlist. The problem is that it starts downloading from the oldest songs. However when I use `--playlist-reverse` it ignores it and still downloads the oldest. This is what I have it as now:

```
youtube-dl --playlist-reverse --playlist-start `ls -1 | wc -l` -wic "URL of Soundcloud playlist"
```

I also understand that youtube-dl automatically doesn't re-download however it scans each file one by one. This becomes tedious when it has to scan 400+ files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option `--playlist-reverse` downloads the playlist videos in reverse order.  It doesn't reverse the order of the playlist itself.  For example, with a playlist containing 5 items:

```
youtube-dl --playlist-start 3 ...
```

will download items 3 then 4 then 5

```
youtube-dl --playlist-start 3 --playlist-reverse ...
```

will download items 5 then 4 then 3, *not* 3, 2, and 1

Answer (score 0):

I have total 135 videos in my playlist. I have successfully downloaded 38 of them. So I manually used this command.

```
youtube-dl --playlist-start 39 -u uname@gmail.com -p mypassword https://www.udemy.com/learn-ethical-hacking-from-scratch/learn/v4/content
```

Its downloading my remaining 97 videos.